# Extract the word before a specific character

Tags: python, regex, string

```
 bool processdata(Message_handler_t* );
```

from this string i want to extract the variable and the parameter i.e. `processdata(Message_handler_t* )` how can I do it using python and regex.
I tried this but it also extracts the word before the variable

```
import re

txt = " bool processdata(Message_handler_t* )"

x = re.findall('\s.+\(.+\)', txt)
print(x)
```

Comment: Trying to work on another source code with regular expressions is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: maybe instead of `.+`  you should use `[a-zA-Z]+` or `\w+` or `[^ ]+` (everything except space) or use not "greedy" expresion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `.+` you could use something more precise - ie. `[a-zA-Z]+` or `\w+` or `[^ ]+`

```
import re

txt = " bool processdata(Message_handler_t* )"

x = re.findall('\w+\(.+\)', txt)
print(x)

x = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\(.+\)', txt)
print(x)

x = re.findall('[^ ]+\(.+\)', txt)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to regex is use ***partition*** method

```
before_key, key, after_key = txt.partition('bool')
```

The output, in this case, would be -

```
before_key=' '
```

```
after_key=' processdata(Message_handler_t* )'
```

And Obviously, the key here is 'bool'